# regex issue in Safari

Tags: javascript, regex, safari, regex-lookarounds

I need to split a string that looks like "12+3-4=" into an array that looks like ["12", "+", "3", "-", "4", "="]

The regex I used works in Chrome, but not in Safari and after doing google search I realized that Safari doesn't yet support lookbehinds. Is there another way to write the following regex so that it does the above, but works in Safari too?

`const arr = displayValue.split(/(?=[\-\+\/\*\=])|(?<=[\-\+\/\*\=])/)`

Comment: Your example suggests that all you need is `\d+|\D`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/H394dh/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `match` with an alternation:

```js
var input = "12+3-4=";
var parts = input.match(/\d+|[*/=+-]/g);
console.log(parts);
```